# Scala Compiler Plugins with a Macro API

Tags: scala, macros

Typically, Scala compiler plugins operate directly on compiler internal data structures and utilities. Unfortunately, compiler APIs change rapidly, with every minor release. As a result, the effort required to maintain a compiler plugin is much larger than to maintain a Scala macro.

Is it possible to write a compiler plugin that uses the stable API of Scala macros? How can one do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely that it's possible to be shielded from the changes in the infrastructure (order of phases, contracts of classes like PluginComponent, etc - that's pretty stable), but it's totally possible to refrain from using `scala.tools.nsc.Global`, which is what actually doesn't have any compatibility guarantees, and use the `scala.reflect.macros.Universe` subset of it.